# PDF bloqueado en windows PdfReaderException: To modify the document the owner password is required

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con `asp.net core 3.1` que me permita copiar un archivo pdf desde una ubicación local y copiarlo en una ruta del servidor. Una vez copiado debería poder desde el servidor abrir ese archivo pdf, leerlo y extraer ciertos párrafos para guardar en base de datos `mysql`, pero el archivo se encuentra bloqueado lo que me genera el siguiente error al momento de ejecutar el evento `OpenReadStream`:

```
PdfReaderException: To modify the document the owner password is required
```

En mi controller tengo el siguiente código:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SubirPDF(IFormFile archivoPDF)
    {
        string dominioPublico = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Dominio"]);
        string path = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Path"]);
        string pathBoletines = (_configuration["DominioPublico:PathBoletines"]);
        string rutaFirma = @"\\" + dominioPublico + "\\" + path + "\\" + pathBoletines;
        
        PdfDocument document;
        
        using (var stream = archivoPDF.OpenReadStream())
        {
            document = PdfReader.Open(stream);
        }

        // Desbloquear el PDF
        document.SecuritySettings.PermitExtractContent = true;
        document.SecuritySettings.PermitAnnotations = true;

        // Guardar el PDF desbloqueado en una memoria temporal o en el servidor
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(outputStream, closeStream: false);
        outputStream.Position = 0;
        if (archivoPDF != null && archivoPDF.Length > 0)
        {
            var rutaGuardar = rutaFirma + "\\" + archivoPDF.FileName;
           // var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(rutaCompartida, FileMode.Create));
            using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaGuardar, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await archivoPDF.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            // Aquí puedes realizar otras operaciones con el archivo guardado, como almacenar la ruta en una base de datos.

            //PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;


            BuscarPalabraEnPDF(rutaGuardar, "");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }



public string BuscarPalabraEnPDF(string rutaPdf, string palabraBuscada)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
        var myArray = configuration.GetSection("MySettings:MyArray").Get<string[]>();
        //var myList = configuration.GetSection("MySettings:MyList").Get<List<string>>();
        //myList.
        using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(rutaPdf))
        {
            string textoPdf = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                string pagina = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);

                textoPdf += pagina;
            }

            int indice = textoPdf.IndexOf("jesus");

            if (indice >= 0)
            {
                int indicePalabraSiguiente = indice + palabraBuscada.Length + 1;
                int longitudPalabraSiguiente = textoPdf.IndexOf(' ', indicePalabraSiguiente) - indicePalabraSiguiente;
                string palabraSiguiente = textoPdf.Substring(indicePalabraSiguiente, longitudPalabraSiguiente);

                // Guardar la palabra siguiente en la base de datos MySQL
               // GuardarPalabraEnMySQL(palabraSiguiente);

                return palabraSiguiente;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Nota:

Mi sistema operativo es `windows 10` intenté abrir el pdf con visor de pdf desde otro so (`linux`) y sí permite edición a diferencia de mi so (`windows`) me aparece bloqueado.

¿Alguien conocerá una posible alternativa de solución para poder desbloquear el archivo sin la clave?

Comment: Todo iba relativamente bien hasta que encontré `¿Alguien conocerá una posible alternativa de solución para poder desbloquear el archivo sin la clave?` Esto, de cierto modo, bordea lo ilegal. Si es algo legal, consulta la contraseña a la persona y/o área que te ofreció dicho documento.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque lo que pide bordea lo ilegal.

Comment: Mis disculpas,  creo que se esta mal interpretando o no me expresé bien, y el comentario no es bien recibido de mi parte, quiero dejar claro que no trabajo de manera ilegal, no hago cosas ilegales y no quiero que esto baje reputación en este foro, si bien explique que en so linux si permite edicion, y ademas que no hago cosas ilegales

Comment: Primero el mismo autor del pdf fue quien me hizo este requerimiento, pero él no tiene niguna clave/contraseña,  en linux no tiene problemas para editar el archivo, el problema lo tengo en windows porque me indica que está PROTEGIDO y yo desarrollo en ese sistema operativo nunca he trabajado con linux, entonces no se si el problema es porque fue creado en linux pero repito el autor me indico que no tiene clave

Comment: Carmen no te preocupes, yo creo que estaba bastante claro que no hay nada ilegal. Intentaste con otro PDF??? Para saber si es un tema puntual de ese archivo o es el código C#

Comment: Investigué sobre las librerias para creación, edición de archivos pdf, y encontré unas compatibles con asp.net core 3.1 y a su vez me permitió copiar el pdf en un servidor y posterior copiar el texto del pdf en un objeto, esto con la finalidad de guardar alguna informacion en base de datos

Comment: Dejo como respuesta el codigo con el que logre solventar

Comment: Aquí tienes otra forma de quitar la contraseña https://www.pdffiller.com/es/functionality/edit-and-remove-password-from-pdf-online-for-free

Comment: Perfecto 
Gracias 
Saludos

Comment: Uno de los usos habituales de la protección del PDF por contraseña es justamente evitar que se pueda hacer un "copiar y pegar", en mi experiencia, no importa el sistema operativo, si el PDF está protegido, vas a necesitar la contraseña.

Answer (score 1):

Para implementar esta solución se requiere instalar BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf por paquetes de NuGet

En mi view cree un input que me permita abrir el explorador de archivos

```
  <input type="file" name="archivoPDF" id="archivoPDF"
 onchange="mostrarBoton()" />
```

Boton para subir archivo

```
 <input class="btn-user" type="submit" id="botonSubmit"
 style="display: none;" value="SUBIR BOLETIN"
 formaction="/Attach/SubirPDF"/>
```

Function js

```
   <script>
           function mostrarBoton() {
               var inputArchivo = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
               var inputArchivo1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
 
               var botonSubmit = document.getElementById('botonSubmit');
               var text1 = document.getElementById('numBoletin');
               var text2 = document.getElementById('numTomo');
               if (inputArchivo.files.length > 0) {
                   botonSubmit.style.display = 'block';
                   text1.style.display = 'block'
                   text2.style.display = 'block'
               } else {
                   botonSubmit.style.display = 'none';
                   text1.style.display = 'none'
                   text2.style.display = 'none'
               }
           }
 
     </script>   
     <script>
           function mostrarBoton() {
               var inputArchivo = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
               var inputArchivo1 = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
 
               var botonSubmit = document.getElementById('botonSubmit');
               var text1 = document.getElementById('numBoletin');
               var text2 = document.getElementById('numTomo');
               if (inputArchivo.files.length > 0) {
                   botonSubmit.style.display = 'block';
                   text1.style.display = 'block'
                   text2.style.display = 'block'
               } else {
                   botonSubmit.style.display = 'none';
                   text1.style.display = 'none'
                   text2.style.display = 'none'
               }
           }
 
     </script>
```

En mi controller

```
 using BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf;
 
   [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> SubirPDF(IFormFile archivoPDF)
     {
         string dominioPublico = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Dominio"]);
         string path = (_configuration["DominioPublico:Path"]);
         string pathBoletines = (_configuration["DominioPublico:PathBoletines"]);
         string rutaFirma = @"\\" + dominioPublico + "\\" + path + "\\" + pathBoletines;           
         
         using (var stream = archivoPDF.OpenReadStream())
         {
             iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            // document = PdfReader.Open(stream);
         }

      
         if (archivoPDF != null && archivoPDF.Length > 0)
         {
             var rutaGuardar = rutaFirma + "\\" + archivoPDF.FileName;

             using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaGuardar, FileMode.Create))
             {
                 await archivoPDF.CopyToAsync(stream);
             }

             using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(rutaGuardar))
             {
                 var options = new PdfTextExtractionOptions
                 {
                     SkipInvisibleText = true,
                     WithFormatting = true
                 };
                 //Copiar en una variable el texto contenido en el pdf
                 string formattedText = pdf.GetText(options);
                 Console.WriteLine(formattedText);
 
 
                 // Crear una lista con las palabras a buscar
                 List<string> palabrasABuscar = new List<string> { "Solicitud N°:", "Fecha de la solicitud:", "Tipo de marca:" };
                 foreach (string palabra in palabrasABuscar)
                 {
                     //Verifico si existe la informacion para insertar el valor en base de daros
                     if (formattedText.Contains(palabra))
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine($"La palabra '{palabra}' se encontró en el texto.");
                         //Codigo para insertar en base de datos
                     }
                 }
             }
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
         else
         {
             return BadRequest();
         }
     }
```